# Parsing error when space is present in test event for Custom R Lambda Environment

Tags: r, aws-lambda

I've followed this tutorial in setting up R as a custom environment for AWS Lambda:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/how-to-use-r-in-aws-lambda/

I've found that I can successfully run code the configured test event does not include a space. To demonstrate this, this is an example handler function:

```
handler <- function(key1) {
    print('test')
```

This will run fine when the test event is as follows:

```
{
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

However, if you were to change the test event to:

```
{
  "key1": "value 1"
}
```

It returns:

```
"parse error: premature EOF\\n                                       {\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value\\n                     (right here) ------^\\n\""
```

As R runs fine with the first test event, I suspect the issue is associated with the bootstrap and runtime.R files within the layer.

This is the bootstrap files:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
  HEADERS="$(mktemp)"

  EVENT_DATA=$(curl -sS -LD "$HEADERS" -X GET "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next")
  REQUEST_ID=$(grep -Fi Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id "$HEADERS" | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d: -f2)

  RESPONSE=$(/opt/R/bin/Rscript /opt/runtime.R $EVENT_DATA)
  RESPONSE_CODE=$?

  if [ $RESPONSE_CODE = 0 ]; then
    OUT="response"
  elif [ $RESPONSE_CODE = 100 ]; then
    OUT="error"
  fi

  curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/$OUT" -d "$RESPONSE"
done
```

This is the runtime.R file:

```
output <- tryCatch(
  {
    library(jsonlite)

    HANDLER <- Sys.getenv("_HANDLER")
    args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
    EVENT_DATA <- args[1]

    HANDLER_split <- strsplit(HANDLER, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
    file_name <- paste0(HANDLER_split[1], ".R")
    function_name <- HANDLER_split[2]
    source(file_name)
    params <- fromJSON(EVENT_DATA)
    output <- tryCatch(
      list(out = do.call(function_name, params), quit_status = 0),
      error = function(e) {
        list(out = e$message, quit_status = 100)
      }
    )

    list(out = output$out, quit_status = output$quit_status)
  },
  error = function(e) {
    list(out = e$message, quit_status = 100)
  }
)

output$out
quit(status = output$quit_status)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it just tips on how to debug this issue. Many thanks.